# Counter won't restart in new instance of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So, I just have an Android app that will increment a counter once per second after you press the Start button. This is done in an AsyncTask and it increments once per second by calling `Thread.sleep(1000);`. When the stop button is pressed the task is cancelled, but when the start button is pressed again, the text on the button changes to "Stop" but the counter does not seem to start (The TextView doesn't update and the `System.out.println` of the counter doesn't show).

When the stop button is pressed, the task is cancelled and a new instance is assigned to the variable:

```
package com.lukechenshui.timelapse;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CounterTask task = new CounterTask();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void toggleTimer(View view){
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.timerButton);
    if(task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
        task.cancel(false);
        task = new CounterTask();
        button.setText("Start");
    }
    else{
        Integer temp = 0;
        task.execute(temp);
        button.setText("Stop");
    }
    System.out.println(task.getStatus());
    }

    private class CounterTask extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        for(int counter = 0; true; counter++){
            try{
                publishProgress(counter);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
            catch(InterruptedException exc){
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
        TextView counterView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);
        counterView.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
        System.out.println(values[0]);
    }
    }

}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.lukechenshui.timelapse.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/timerButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="toggleTimer"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/counterTextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Example output:

```
//Pressed start
I/System.out: Starting counter!
I/System.out: RUNNING
I/System.out: 0
I/System.out: 1
I/System.out: 2
I/System.out: 3
I/System.out: 4
I/System.out: 5
I/System.out: 6
//Pressed stop
I/System.out: Stopping counter!
I/System.out: PENDING
//Pressed start
I/System.out: Starting counter!
I/System.out: RUNNING
//Pressed stop
I/System.out: Stopping counter!
I/System.out: PENDING
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `temp` variable being passed to `execute`?

Comment: @cricket_007 It doesn't serve a purpose. I could've sworn I got an error earlier about a parameter being necessary, but I just tested it and it is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: @cricket_007 I replaced the `true` in the for loop with `!isCancelled()` and it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the AsyncTask has an infinite loop and isn't being canceled.

You can replace `true` with `!isCanceled()`. Once canceled, the AsyncTask should end.

You may also want to set the task to null when you stop it